# Weighting terms on pooled variances

Tags: variance

Consider the `pooled variance` as described in this wiki article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pooled_variance :

[image]

My observation is that the weighting terms

[image]

simply cancel out the `Bessel's correction` weighting factors. So then the result is simply

[image]

But then we no longer have count-based weightings on each of the variance terms!  I must be missing something here - any insights/corrections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that this cancellation occurs, so for each sub-sample you get

$$(n_k-1) s_k^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{n_k} (y_{k,i} - \bar{y}_k)^2.$$

Each of these terms is a sum of $n_k$ squared deviations of the individual data points from the sub-sample mean.  There is no need for any further weighting on the terms, since the summation already gives a quantity that is proportionate to the count of terms.

Comment: oh ya - the summation is over the individual sample sizes!  wrote it down but still "missed" it. thx.